# Ionic 3 app is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic3

I am developing a `hybrid` app using `ionic-3`. My Ionic 3 app is not working in iOS. My app is working well in Android but when I try to run in iOS, the app is not initializing. It's stuck on the splash screen and it's giving error this error:

> NSURLconnection finished with error code 1100

XCode Error:

```
2018-03-08 17:12:41.591207+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.4.0 is starting.
2018-03-08 17:12:41.721496+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-03-08 17:12:45.238570+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-03-08 17:12:45.240832+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-03-08 17:12:45.264001+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] Using UIWebView
2018-03-08 17:12:45.268870+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.118017ms
2018-03-08 17:12:45.273374+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 4.155993ms
2018-03-08 17:12:45.273905+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.128984ms
2018-03-08 17:12:45.275001+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][camerapreview] 0.870943ms
2018-03-08 17:12:45.275385+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] Starting Facebook Connect plugin
2018-03-08 17:12:45.275635+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][facebookconnectplugin] 0.370979ms
2018-03-08 17:12:45.383774+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][file] 107.890010ms
2018-03-08 17:12:45.994930+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 610.774994ms
2018-03-08 17:12:46.038368+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 40.236950ms
2018-03-08 17:12:46.051996+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EB04963A-60B9-49F0-8F79-1B87EB1DC447/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-03-08 17:12:46.053144+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: selfstuff.daily.com, source account management: 1
2018-03-08 17:12:53.638244+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][socialsharing] 7599.534988ms
2018-03-08 17:12:53.644387+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 5.487919ms
2018-03-08 17:12:53.645309+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 8376.922011ms
2018-03-08 17:13:02.236624+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2018-03-08 17:13:23.400508+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-03-08 17:13:23.530754+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
2018-03-08 17:13:26.170761+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:184450] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2018-03-08 17:13:26.686032+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:184442] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-03-08 17:13:26.686921+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:184442] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-03-08 17:13:26.687874+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:184442] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-03-08 17:13:26.688890+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:184442] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2018-03-08 17:13:26.882219+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:184450] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2018-03-08 17:13:26.882719+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:184450] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2018-03-08 17:13:28.746448+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] Finished load of: file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EB04963A-60B9-49F0-8F79-1B87EB1DC447/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A4777C69-7382-4D3D-A3EF-85C315FF8A8F/SelfStuff%20Daily.app/www/index.html
2018-03-08 17:13:39.250569+0300 SelfStuff Daily[14041:183749] THREAD WARNING: ['File'] took '409.652832' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

Comment: try Cordova iOS 4.5.4

Comment: I have tried but it's not working. Build fail In Cordova iOS 4.5.4

Comment: One more thing if i use ionic word in any command it's giving error so i have to use only cordova command like cordova platform add ios,cordova build ios etc..

Comment: step.1 defult ionic 2 splash images size 2732*2732 
step.2 add images path : Myproject\ resource\ splash.png Step.3 after then command run ionic cordova resources ios step.4 ionic cordova buils ios

Comment: @second_Soution :  cordova platform update ios

Comment: I have tried but it's not working.